# Showing custom product attribute in tab

Tags: php, magento, custom-attributes

I have created custom product attribute in new attribute group PB. I want to show this attribute group in tab.
I have created attributes as follows.

```
$eav = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup', 'catalog_setup');/
$eav->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'pb_pbgsp_upload', array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Last upload timestampt',
    'global' => 2,
    'user_defined' => 0,
    'required' => 0,
    'visible' => 1,
    'default' => 0,
    'group' => 'PB'
));
```

I have created custom tab in product edit page in magento admin successfully. Now want to show the attribute to the tab